# javascript spoiler помогите сделать спойлер

Tags: javascript

Есть шапка чата, и ниже есть сам блок чата где летят сообщеньки. Помогите написать простенький код, что бы при нажатии на иконку icon-down блок чата скрылся, и иконка поменялась на icon-up. Главное напишите где какой element вставить  с иконками, они просто взяты с font-awesome, я пытался качать плагины, но плавного появления не добылся.

```
<div class="hidden"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
<section class = "message-block"></section>код
```

Comment: Чистый JS нужен? Без jQuery?

Comment: ++ чистый, страница и так тяжолая. 900 строк html кодп

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понял где как именно выглядит чат, но вот вам пример с плавным появлением и сменой стрелок из font-awesome

```js
var chatVisibility = true;

function toggleChatVisibility() {
  var chatBlock = document.querySelector(".message-block");
  var arrows = document.querySelector("#toggleArrows");
  chatBlock.classList.toggle('message-block-hidden');
  arrows.classList.toggle('fa-arrow-down');

}
```

```css
.message-block {
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #eee;
  transition: .3s ease all;
}

.message-block-hidden {
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.message-block-hidden>* {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button onClick="toggleChatVisibility()">
<i id="toggleArrows" class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>

<section class="message-block">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga suscipit rem sint officiis animi et architecto, a cupiditate esse, nulla.</p>
</section>
```